# the real projective line is a submanifold of $\mathbb{RP}^{n} $

Tags: smooth-manifolds, projective-space, submanifold

The exercise says the following:

> Show that a projective line is a submanifold of $\mathbb{RP}^{n}$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^{1}$.

I think this is a consequence of the following result

> 1. if $q:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}\to \mathbb{RP}^{n}$ be the usual quotient map.  For any subspace $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $q(U\setminus \{0\})$ is a submanifold
>    of $\mathbb{RP}^{n}$ of dimension equal to $dim(U) − 1$.

for the previous result if $dim(U)=2$, then $q(U\setminus \{0\})$ is a projective line and a submanifold of $\mathbb{RP}^{n}$. I have shown that the $q$ function is smooth, but I don't know how to show that the image below $q$ is a submanifold. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What does dipheomorphic mean?

Comment: I think that $\mathcal T_1$ is dipheomorphic to $\mathcal T_2$ if $\exists f: \mathcal T_1 \to \mathcal T_2$ where $f$ is a differentiable homeomorphism (so its inverse is also differentiable).

Comment: Do you mean "diffeomorphic"?

Comment: Is it not enough to just consider the embedding $[(a,b)] \in \mathbb{RP}^1 \mapsto [(a,b,0,\ldots,0)]\in \mathbb{RP}^n$?

Comment: " For any subspace $U \subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$" may be confusing. You mean *linear subspaces*.